# WooCommerce or any other plugin: Deliver JS and CSS through CDN without using a Plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, plugins-url

I have a straightforward question:

How do I change the links (base URL) of the JS and CSS assets provided by WooCommerce (or any other plugin) in order to use a CDN?

The only requirements I have:

- I do not want to use any plugin.
- I do not want to change any code in `wp-content/plugins` as this will be overwritten by the next updates.
- I do not want to change `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` or `WP_PLUGIN_URL`, because other plugins and plugin components rely on this path and I don't want / can not upload the whole plugin code to the CDN (correct me please if I'm wrong in any way).

To be precise, I'm talking about the following assets:

- `example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js`
- `example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js'`
- `example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js'`
- `example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/woocommerce.min.js`
- `example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js`
- `example.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-poly-integration/public/js/Cart.min.js`

I checked the plugin code and they register the assets like this:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery-blockui', WC()->plugin_url() . 
'/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI' . $suffix .
'.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.70', true );
```

Sure, I could change the `plugin_url()` function, but that would have two disadvantages: First other components rely on the `plugin_url` (I would brake other functionality) and second, I would loose the changes with every new update.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`WC()->plugin_url()` is basically a wrapper for the core function [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/).  That functions return value is filtered. `return apply_filters( 'plugins_url', $url, $path, $plugin );`  So you should be able to add a filter to that hook that returns the initial value if `$plugin` isn't woocommerce, then checks if the path or URL leads to one of the scripts you're trying to replace and sends the appropriate value on from there.

Comment: But in this case I would change the plugin url for each component of the plugin and then I would brake other functionality in the plugin, or am I wrong with that assumption?

Comment: If you need it to be that specific then you could use a regex to check if the `$url` or `$path` variable was specifically for one of the scripts you're looking to change and only make changes if it is.